# TypeError: barplot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given

Tags: python, seaborn, bar-chart

Can someone tell me whats wrong here

```
#stemming all the words to their root word
stemmer = SnowballStemmer(language='english')
stem=[]
for word in lines:
    stem.append(stemmer.stem(word))
stem[:20]
#removes stopwords (very common words in a sentence)
stem2 = []
for word in stem:
    if word not in nlp.Defaults.stop_words:
        stem2.append(word)
#creates a new dataframe for the stem and shows the count of the most used words
df = pd.DataFrame(stem2)
df=df[0].value_counts()
df #shows the new dataframe
```

I don't know what's wrong here, The error I got, when I'm running these code ⬇⬇⬇

```
#plots the top 20 used words
df = df[:20]
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
sns.barplot(df.values, df.index, alpha=0.8)
plt.title('Top Words Overall')
plt.xlabel('Count of words', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Word from Tweet', fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Then got these error

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-3371fa9e7860> in <module>
      2 df = df[:20]
      3 plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
----> 4 sns.barplot(df.values, df.index, alpha=0.8)
      5 plt.title('Top Words Overall')
      6 plt.xlabel('Count of words', fontsize=12)

TypeError: barplot() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
<Figure size 720x360 with 0 Axes>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using seaborn's barplot function. In the future, it would be helpful to include import statements in your code snippets, so readers know what `sns` stands for.

Looking at the [seaborn documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.barplot.html), it looks like `barplot` expects `x` and `y` to be provided as named arguments.  In your case, I think you'd want something like this:

```
sns.barplot(x=df.values, y=df.index, alpha=0.8)
```